# Spring Data Elastic Search: ElasticSearchDateConverter fails to convert LocalDateTime with given format

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Data support for Elasticsearch. Here is the date field mapping:

```
@Field(type=FieldType.Date, format= DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second)
private LocalDateTime dateOfCreation;
```

I want to store the date in index which is retrieved from database e.g. 2019-08-30T15:27:47
But when saving it in index, it's giving following error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ElasticsearchDateConverter$PatternDateFormatter.format(ElasticsearchDateConverter.java:327) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ElasticsearchDateConverter.format(ElasticsearchDateConverter.java:97) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.TemporalPropertyValueConverter.write(TemporalPropertyValueConverter.java:65) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Writer.propertyConverterWrite(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:1081) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Writer.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:902) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Writer.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:781) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Writer.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:759) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Writer.writeCollectionInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:873) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Writer.createCollection(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:1093) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$Writer.writeProperty(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:944) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
```

I tried all date formats given by elasticsearch documentation, but It's giving the same error as above
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/mapping-date-format.html

I'm using spring-data-elasticsearch version 4.3.0, elasticsearch version 7.15.2

can someone help me with this error, please?

Comment: what do you mean by `retrieved from database`? Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your index has been initially created with the wrong format date. Try to delete your index and rebuild it with the right format.